# Java: actionPerformed method not firing when button clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm creating a gui application that requires some simple input, however, when I click the button in the JFrame the actionPerformed method I'm using is not fired/firing (nothing happens). I can't seem to figure out what I've missed (new to java if that helps). thanks for any help/advice.

Here is all the code:

```
//gui class
public class guiUser extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JButton buttonClose_;
private final int frameWidth = 288;
private final int frameHeight = 263;
private final int closeX = 188;
private final int closeY = 195;
private final int closeWidth = 75;
private final int closeHeight = 25;

public guiUser() {

    setTitle("Create a User");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(null);
    setSize(frameWidth, frameHeight);
    setResizable(false);

    buttonClose_ = new JButton("Exit");
    buttonClose_.setLayout(null);
    buttonClose_.setSize(closeWidth, closeHeight);
    buttonClose_.setBounds(closeX, closeY, closeWidth, closeHeight);
    buttonClose_.setLocation(closeX, closeY);
    add(buttonClose_);

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == buttonClose_) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you wish to exit       user creation?");
        if(result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        } 
    }
}

//tests the gui
public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        guiUser gUser_ = new guiUser();
        gUser_.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add an action listener to your button component like this.

```
closeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        closeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
    }
});

private void closeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    dispose();
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying I must implement the un-used methods, which is fine, but then there are two of the same methods? one outside the constructor and one within being set by the action listener. sorry for noob question.

Comment: You probably don't want to implements ActionListener as part of your class. I would remove that implementation part and then just declare the action listener like it is in my code example. I took it from a working application I have. Let me know if it works or you still get an error message.

Answer (score 5):

You must add an "addActionListener to your button

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you mind posting a small example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use @182Much's method as was discussed here: [java detect clicked buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901720/java-detect-clicked-buttons)
Hope it is helpful if there are still concerns.