# Passing text field value into a constructor

Tags: java, constructor

Ok, I have a program I am doing for class. I have to take the input form the text field, ad throw it into an overloaded constructor that takes a string as an argument. There are a few other things I have to do with constructors as well, so in my code you'll see some stuff that is outside of this question. also, I am not posting my methods because it's a big part of the homework, and those all work fine, (prior to my attempt at passing info to the constructor). What I would like to know is i there is a way to pass the text field info into the constructor, because I have been going at this for a couple hours now, but it's becoming plainly obvious that I don't understand this. If you just want to direct me to somewhere that I can learn how to do this I would appreciate it.

Code:

```
package lab4;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.lang.Iterable.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Lab4 extends JFrame{

private JTextField jTextField1;
private JButton doSome;
private JLabel ansTxt;
private JLabel asciSum;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JLabel jLabel3;
private JLabel jLabel4;
private JLabel jLabel5;
private JLabel jLabel6;
private JLabel lowCnt;
private JLabel numDigit;
private JLabel upCnt;
private JLabel vowelCnt;
private String userInput = jTextField1.getText();

public Lab4()
{        
    initComponents(); 
}
public Lab4(String x)
{
    this.userInput = x;
}
public Lab4(char[] x)
{

}
public Lab4(byte[] x)
{

}

private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    doSome = new JButton();
    ansTxt = new JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new JLabel();
    jLabel6 = new JLabel();
    asciSum = new JLabel();
    vowelCnt = new JLabel();
    numDigit = new JLabel();
    upCnt = new JLabel();
    lowCnt = new JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);
    setFont(new java.awt.Font("Comic Sans MS", 1, 12)); // NOI18N

    jLabel1.setText("Enter a string Here and I'll show you some info about it!");

    doSome.setToolTipText("This Will Do Something");
    doSome.setInheritsPopupMenu(true);
    doSome.setLabel("Click Me When Your Done!");
    doSome.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            doSomeActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    ansTxt.setText("ASCII SUM:");

    jLabel3.setText("Number of Vowels:");

    jLabel4.setText("Number of Digits:");

    jLabel5.setText("Number Of Uppercase:");

    jLabel6.setText("Number Of Lowercase:");

    GroupLayout layout = new GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(ansTxt)
                        .addComponent(jLabel5, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(lowCnt)
                        .addComponent(vowelCnt)
                        .addComponent(asciSum)
                        .addComponent(numDigit)
                        .addComponent(upCnt)))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(95, 95, 95)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(doSome, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
            .addContainerGap(239, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(doSome)
            .addGap(34, 34, 34)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(ansTxt)
                .addComponent(asciSum))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addComponent(vowelCnt))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addComponent(numDigit))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                .addComponent(upCnt))
            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addComponent(lowCnt))
            .addContainerGap(157, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}

private void doSomeActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
{  
   String takeTfIn = this.jTextField1.getText(); 
    this.asciSum.setText(getAsciiSum(takeTfIn));
    this.vowelCnt.setText(getNumVowels(takeTfIn));
    this.numDigit.setText(getNumDigits(takeTfIn));
    this.upCnt.setText(getNumUpperCase(takeTfIn));
    this.lowCnt.setText(getNumLowerCase(takeTfIn));
}

 // Excluded methods go here...


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Lab4 test = new Lab4();
    test.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question; you want to pass the contents of a text field into the class that creates and displays the text field from which you'll get the text to create and display the text field from which... well.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the problem is ... if you want the constructor declared as `public Lab4(String x)` to be used, then `new Lab4("text")` or `new Lab4(some-other-string-expression)` will do it.  You may also want to make sure _all_ your constructors call `initComponents()`, because otherwise that won't happen automatically.

Comment: I have to pass the user input form the one text filed I have, into the constructor with the string, which can then be used for to input to all my methods. We have to do this because I am assuming at some point the teacher will have us use the other constructors to pass in non-string data, which will then be converted to a string, passed through the string constructor, and off onto the methods, (which simply add up ascii characters, scan for vowels, upper and lower case letters, and so on.)

Comment: A constructor is called when an object (here, a `Lab4` object) is first created.  If you're going to pass a string into the constructor, you need to know the string before the object is created.  But you have a JTextField that is _part_ of a `Lab4` object, and therefore it won't exist until _after_ the object is created.  So if you're trying to get text from the JTextField to pass into the `Lab4` constructor, you will need the ability to go backward in time, which Java doesn't support.  Maybe you need a different class to hold the JTextField?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create new instance of lab4 after you fill tex field value and click on submit. on click of submit you can do like this

```
   this.setVisible(false);//Hide current instance
   Lab4 test = new Lab4(this.jTextField1.getText()); // create new instance
   test.setVisible(true);  // set new instance visible
```

Don't forget to add following constructor:

```
 public Lab4 (String value) 
  {   
  this.jTextField1.setText(value); // if you like to set value back to textbox 
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I pass that into my doSomeActionPerformed so I can get the work done off of the user input? I've tried Lab4 test = new Lab4(this.jTextField1.getText()); and then inserting test into the methods : this.asciSum.setText(getAsciiSum(test));, but I just get errors

Comment: why you need to pass value into doSomeActionPerformed? if your instance has value assigned to jTextField1 then you should be able to access it's value in doSomeActionPerformed method, because it is internal method. You need to check binding of your actionPerformed method with your component. See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8720793/1356109 it might help.

Comment: Each method has to hold a string, so like this: private String getAsciiSum(String x). I have to be able to pass the user input, from the constructor, into the method, which is what I use the doSomeActionPerformed to do

Comment: So I tried this: Lab4 test = new Lab4();
        String x = test.toString(); 
        this.asciSum.setText(getAsciiSum(x));
        this.vowelCnt.setText(getNumVowels(x));  and it passed along something, and allowed the program to run, but the counts are all way off. When it type in 1234, i get a count of 32 lower case letters in the string
        this.numDigit.setText(getNumDigits(x));
        this.upCnt.setText(getNumUpperCase(x));
        this.lowCnt.setText(getNumLowerCase(x));

Comment: String x = test.toString();   ????? test is your object right, how u converting it to string?

Comment: I actually don't know. This part of the assignment is really confusing the crud out of me. This is what its actually asking me for: `Constructors
Default (no argument) sets the data section to an empty string
An array of bytes - You will have to convert the array of bytes to a string and set the data section.
An array of chars - You will also have to convert the array of chars to a string and set the data section.
A string - This will be your working constructor. What that means is that all other constructors will call this one.`

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding what it's asking for. There are also two methods which I haven't done yet : `toString - This is a simple accessor method that returns the data section
setString - This is a simple mutator method that sets the data section.` is there a chance that those are affecting what I am trying to do? I haven't done them yet because I haven't gotten any feedback as to what they do. I was planning on seeing a tutor on Thursday, because I am obviously missing something